# how to load a local csv file in tensorflow using Dataset API in colab

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I'm trying to upload a csv file from colab to tensorflow using

```
tensorflow.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(io.StringIO(uploaded[ 'data.csv'].decode('utf-8')))
```

and i'm getting this error

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (<_io.StringIO object at 0x7f4bb80e8e58>) with an unsupported type (<class '_io.StringIO'>) to a Tensor.
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files in the following way:

```py
from google.colab import files
import pandas as pd
import io

uploader = files.upload()
train_data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploader['data.csv'].decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't want to use pandas. I want to directly load CSV file in tensorflow. Is there a way to do it in colab without using pandas?